# How to loop specific powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting, java, wmi

I need to uninstall Java from several computers in my network.  After almost all day of Googling it seems the best way to do this is with a Powershell script.  I found one that I have tested on a few computers that works pretty well but I'm not a PS wiz and am unsure of how to loop it through a list of computers. I'd like to just have a txt document with a list of computer names - one name per line.  Is this easy to do? Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the ps script obtained from [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130725231816/3techies.com/?p=132)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Foreach($C In Get-ADComputer -Filter *)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $C.Name { Do-Something }
}
```

---

```
Foreach($C In Get-Content C:\ComputerList.txt)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $C { Do-Something }
}
```

Where `Do-Something` is probably an msiexec.exe command or something.
This requires a couple of things to work. WinRM (aka Powershell Remoting) to be enabled on the computers, and network connectivity for RPC.